# cat file_name | grep "something" results "cat: grep: No such file or directory" in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written shell script which reads commands from input file and execute commands. I have command like:

```
cat linux_unit_test_commands | grep "dmesg"
```

in the input file. I am getting below error message while executing shell script:

```
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: grep: No such file or directory
cat: "dmesg": No such file or directory
```

Script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while read line
 do
     output=`$line`
     echo $output >> logs
 done < $1
```

Below is input file(example_commands):

```
ls
date
cat linux_unit_test_commands | grep "dmesg"
```

Execute: ./linux_unit_tests.sh example_commands

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The [`cat` is Useless](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) anyway.  Use `grep "dmesg" linux_unit_test_commands` instead.

Comment: See here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special characters like `|` and `"` are not parsed after expanding variables; the only processing done after variable expansion is word splitting and wildcard expansions. If you want the line to be parsed fully, you need to use `eval`:

```
while read line
do
    output=`eval "$line"`
    echo "$output" >> logs
done < $1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be wondering why its not working with cat command.
Then here is the answer for your question.

```
output=`$line` i.e. output=`cat linux_unit_test_commands | grep "dmesg"`
```

here the cat command will take (linux_unit_test_commands | grep "dmesg") all these as arguments i.e. fileNames.

From Man page:

**SYNTAX :** cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Script is OK!**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;
do
    output=`$line`
    echo $output >> logs
done < $1
```

To make it work you need to change **'cat: "dmesg": No such file or directory'** to **'grep "dmesg" linux_unit_test_commands'**. It will work!

```
cat linux_unit_test_commands

ls
date
grep "dmesg" linux_unit_test_commands
```